# Retrieve range of matched token with Lex/Yacc

Tags: regex, nlp, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I'm using Lex to parse a given input string in a C program. everything works so far, but I would like to know the range of the matched token in the original input string. Is this possible?

yytext gives me the matched token, but not the range of the token in the original string. Since the token could exist several times in the input string but doesn't necessarily be valid every time, I can't simply search for the first/last/etc. occurrence of the token in the input string - I need to know the exact range of the match as the following example demonstrates:

Example input: "Remind me to buy milk in 5 min"

```
token "min":  range 27-30 (and not 2-5)
```

I've looked into yy_buffer_state already, but it doesn't seem to hold the information I need.

Comment: Please be aware of tagging your questions. This has nothing to do w/ the Adobe/Apache Framework so the Flex tag should not be used.  gnu-flex is used for the lexical analyzer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep a running count of characters as they are consumed: basically count += strlen(yytext) in each flex rule. In the rule that matches keywords or variables or whatever it is you need the range of (I would call them the co-ordinates myself) you need int start = count; count += strlen(yytext); int end = count, then start and end are the co-ordinates.

Comment: I was hoping for something more elegant, but thanks, that's an easy solution nevertheless.